# Why are Ohm's law and Ampere's law contrasting in Magnetohydrodynamics?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance, magnetohydrodynamics

In the Magnetohydrodynamics the electric current is given by the Ampere's law is:

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{B}=\mu_0\mathbf{J}$$

where $\mathbf{B}$ is the magnetic field and $\mathbf{J}$ is the electric current.

Now, consider Ohm's law:

$$\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{V}\times\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{J}/\sigma$$

where $\mathbf{E}$ is electric field and $\mathbf{V}$ is the fluid velocity.

The question is if there is a uniform external magnetic exerting in the absence of an electric field, Ampere's law says $\mathbf{J}=0$ while the Ohm's law says $\mathbf{J}\neq 0$, why?

Answer (score 1):

If the external magnetic field is uniform, total field $\mathbf B$ need not be uniform; there is contribution to total field due to current in the medium. If total field $\mathbf B$ is somehow made uniform, then current density vanishes. Then $\mathbf E + \mathbf V \times \mathbf B = 0$, so electric field is determined by the magnetic field.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what you've asserted, assuming $\mathbf{E}=0$ and $\mathbf{B}=\text{const}$, Ohm's law does *not* make the claim that $\mathbf{J}\neq0$, it makes *no* claim on the value of $\mathbf{J}$ as there is an additional component you've neglected: the velocity (i.e., you have two unknowns & 1 equation). So by itself, it can only make the claim that the current density is orthogonal to the velocity & magnetic field,
$$
\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{J}
$$

It is only by using additional information, in the form of Ampere's law wherein we find that $\mathbf{J}=0$, that Ohm's law reduces to,
$$\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}=0$$
which means that the velocity $\mathbf{v}$ must be parallel to the magnetic field.

Comment: Consider a pipe carrying water, I place two magnets on the pipe's diameter and far away enough to make a uniform magnetic field which is prependicular to the velocity field, assume there is no electric field, in this configuration $\vec{V}\times\vec{B}=\vec{J}\neq 0$ according to the Ohm's law,but $\vec{J}$ is zero based on Ampere's law, how do you justify this?

Comment: I'd justify it by saying one of your assumptions must be wrong. For instance, the electric field may not actually be zero due to the moving particles (typically one assumes *charged* particles in the analysis, rather than *neutral* ones like water) via the Lorentz force. Or that Ohm's law, being an approximation, doesn't hold (cf. [this PSE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/195020/25301) or the linked [question here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/40907/25301)).