# Resistance of a conductor shaped like a ball

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

As we know, there is an equation for the resistance of conductors given their dimensions, which is:
[image]

where $l$ is the length of the conductor, measured in metres [$m$], $A$ is the cross-section area of the conductor measured in square metres [$m^2$], and $\rho$ is the electrical resistivity of the material, measured in ohm-metres ($\Omega m$).

And that formula requires that the cross-sectional area $A$ be constant, by wich I mean that the cross-sectional are of any part of the conductor should be the same.

Now, I am asking how can we deal with conductors shaped like a ball or a pyramid, which have different cross-sectional areas from one part of them and other ones.

Can anyone help me with that problem, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [General integral to find resistance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21877/)

Comment: Check [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21877/general-integral-to-find-resistance?rq=1)  question. The question already contains an approximate answer and the accepted answer gives the general solution.

Comment: I still need someone to set up the integrals because I SUCK  at calculus.

Comment: You are not alone ;) . However, you should then reformulate your question and show how far you got by yourself. The title can stay the same. Note that the answer will depend on how you connect to the ball and therefore might be far from trivial. The simplest, but not very interesting solution can be found for a point contact which will lead to infinite resistance. For other configurations an analytic solution might be difficult and simulations might be necessary.